# Problems installing R "sm" package on Mac

Tags: r, package, installation

I had some problems when I tried to install "sm" package. It showed `make: gfortran: No such file or directory` and the installing process was cancelled.
Can anyone tell me what I can do to fix it?

Comment: https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/

Comment: install gnu fortran. and make sure it is available in default path.

Comment: @hrbrmstr links to complete instructions, but they aren't quick to follow.  It's easier to just install the pre-built binary of `sm` version 2.2-5.4  that is offered when you run `install.packages("sm")`.  It's not the very latest version, but it might be good enough.

Comment: @user2554330 makes a good point `sm 2.2-5.4` is binary on CRAN right now but `sm 2.2-5.6` is just source and if you're trying to install the latter, just wait a few days (or do the `gfortran` install dance).